Stuck with a sed in a complex git alias
So far, this alias in ~/.gitconfig is working fine :
all  = "! \
    r() { echo $@ | sed 's,/.git,,' ;}; \
    f() { cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} ; find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' -exec echo $(r {}) \\; -exec git -C {} $@ \\; ; }; f"

I can use it in a directory where I have several git repos, with for exemple git all branch -a, and it outputs :
./foo/.git
  remotes/origin/dev/foo
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
./foo2/.git
  remotes/origin/dev/foo2
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
./foo3/.git
  remotes/origin/dev/foo3
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master


The last thing I'd like to do is to modify how the name of the directory is displayed : instead of ./foo/.git I'd like somthing more readable, like [foo]
My problem is that the sed in the r function doesn't work, it seems totally ignored.
I tried simple things like sed 's,i,x,', it doesn't work.
I know I could use a bash function in my .bashrc or something like that, but I prefer to use git aliases that I can copy/paste easily on my servers.

r is called as soon as find is called to construct the argument for -exec; it is not called by find for each file it locates. You probably want a single -exec sh -c '...' _ {} argument.

Yes!
It works fine!
all  = "!f() { cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} ; find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' -exec sh -c 'echo {} | sed s,/.git,,' \\; -exec git -C {} $@ \\; ; }; f"

Complex aliases are evil. Better put the git-all script in your PATH.

+1 for git-all: if you place a script (any executable actually) named git-[foo] on your path, then running git [foo] will call that script.  You can write your code in a script named git-all, and avoid escaping.

Thank you @LeGEC and terrorrussia-keeps-killing but as I said, I want to have just a .gitconfig to copy/paste.
That's more complicated for escaping, but that's easier to maintain  all over my servers.

Thanx to @chepner  it works now, using -exec sh -c.
     all  = "!f() { \
      cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} ; \
      find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' \
       -exec sh -c 'echo [{}] | sed s,/.git,, | sed s,./,,' \\; \
       -exec git -C {} $@ \\; ; \
      }; f" 

What a mess with escaping, but at last, it works.
